# color property is ignored then defining elements in different files

Tags: qt, qml

I try to split up the code into several files.

I have theese two qml-files:

```
// MainWindow.qml
import QtQuick 2.12
import QtQuick.Controls 1.4
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.2


ApplicationWindow {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 240
    title: qsTr("Hi Hi")
    color: "red"

    GridLayout {
        anchors.top: parent.top
        anchors.left: parent.left
        anchors.right: parent.right
        anchors.margins: 9

        MessageLabel{
            message: "debug"
        }
        MessageLabel {
        }
        MessageLabel {
            message: "is critical"
        }
    }
}
```

and

```
// MessageLabel.qml
import QtQuick 2.12

Rectangle {
    height: 50
    color: "blue"
    property string message: "debug message"

    Column {
        anchors.fill: parent
        padding: 5.0
        spacing: 2
        Text {
            text: message
        }
    }
}
```

I expect that the message rectangles are backround colored blue but they are red or transparent:
[image]

I didn't find any hint what is wrong here...

Comment: Your Rectangle has no width.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this happens because you didn't set width and height for the message rects:
look at this :
[image]
[image]

**I change it to this code:**

```
// MainWindow.qml
import QtQuick 2.12
import QtQuick.Controls 1.4
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.2


ApplicationWindow {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 240
    title: qsTr("Hi Hi")
    color: "red"

    GridLayout {
        anchors.top: parent.top
        anchors.left: parent.left
        anchors.right: parent.right
        anchors.margins: 9

        MessageLabel{
            width: 145

            message: "debug"
        }
        MessageLabel {
            width: 135
        }
        MessageLabel {
            width: 150
            message: "is critical"
        }
    }
}
```

**Out Put :**

[image]

Answer (score 2):

As noted, the error is caused because the item does not have a width. In that case there are several solutions, one of them is to set the width as the other post points out but since you are going to use layouts it is better to set those values through implicitWidth and implicitHeight that are used directly by the layouts, and for example you can take as reference the size of the Column.

**MessageLabel.qml**

```
import QtQuick 2.12

Rectangle {
    property string message: "debug message"

    implicitWidth: column.implicitWidth
    implicitHeight: column.implicitHeight
    color: "blue"

    Column {
        id: column

        anchors.fill: parent
        padding: 5
        spacing: 2

        Text {
            text: message
        }

    }

}
```

Output

[image]